# Getting Error in admin Configuration while Clear Browser Cache

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

Getting Error in admin Configuration after clearing Browser Cache & History. I am getting the below error on refresh.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object
>   in
>   /var/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml
>   on line 33

Below is my file code on line number 33

```
<?php echo $this->__("Logged in as %s", $this->escapeHtml($this->getUser()->getUsername())) ?><span class="separator">|</span><?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full') ?><span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getLogoutLink() ?>" class="link-logout"><?php echo $this->__('Log Out') ?></a>
```

Comment: This means there is no active admin login but for some reason redirection to the login form failed. Try the following: Clear cookies, open `https://yourdomain/index.php/admin/index/login` and log in again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have any method name `Username` in `$this->getUser()` .

First do one thing try to see the all method and variables in `$this->getUser()` using `var_dump` method. And then search for `user`.

**Hope that will help you to debug your problem.**

Answer (score -1):

This is really cleared that there is an error in `header.phtml` on line number 33, See what is `getUsername()` function there, or send me the `header.phtml` content.

> getUsername() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml`on
>   line 33

`getUsername()` is not an recognized function because this is not define in `header.php` So here is the way you can retrieve customer information in `header.phtml` file.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
   $customerdata = $session->getCustomer();
  $uname =  $customerdata->geUsername();
} 
else {$uname = ''; }
```

Add above lines of code & replace your line of code with below line

```
__("Logged in as %s", $this->escapeHtml($uname)) ?>|formatDate(null, 'full') ?>|getLogoutLink() ?>" class="link-logout">__('Log Out') ?>
```

Comment: Hi Amit , I edited my Question please find the default code